# Spotfire CustomTool Prompt dialog does NOT show when executed from IronPython script

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

We have developed a CustomTool for the Spotfire Web Player. When on a TablePlot a row has been marked and on a right-click the tool shows a menu item on the context menu.  When that menu item is selected a pop-up shows. The user can fill-in some data and click Ok on the pop-up and that data gets saved to a database. This works great!

This tool gets registered with Spotfire in the AddIn like so:

```cs
protected override void RegisterTools(ToolRegistrar registrar)
{
    base.RegisterTools(registrar);
    registrar.Register<TablePlotCellContext>(new CustomToolOneWeb());
}
```

And the pop-up gets registered with Spotfire in the AddIn like so:

```cs
protected override void RegisterViews(AddIn.ViewRegistrar registrar)
{
    base.RegisterViews(registrar);
    registrar.Register(typeof(PromptControl), typeof(PopupModel), typeof(Popup));
}
```

The yield line in the following code causes the popup to be launched.

```cs
public class CustomToolOneWeb: CustomTool<TablePlotCellContext>
{
    ...
    protected override IEnumerable<object> ExecuteAndPromptCore(TablePlotCellContext context)
    {
        PopupModel popupSettings = null;
        try
        {
            popupSettings = new PopupModel();
            ...
            yield return popupSettings;
        }
        finally
        {
            ...
        }
        yield break; 
    }
    ...
}
```

The above code works great!

Now the business came up with the requirement that the pop-up also needs to be accessed via a button in a TextArea.

So I created a new CustomTool with pretty much the same functionality as the original tool. The button in the TextArea executes an IronPython script which in turn executes my new CustomTool. However the pop-up does NOT show. Through debugging I found out that my new CustomTool does get executed. At the point where I expect the pop-up to be launched nothing happens and the debugger jumps to the next line.

For the new CustomTool I added the following line to the RegisterTools method:

```cs
registrar.Register<Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Page>(new CustomToolTwoWeb());
```

And the class for the new CustomTool has only been altered on the level of the generics (Page instead of TablePlotCellContext):

```cs
public class CustomToolTwoWeb : CustomTool<Page>
{
    protected override IEnumerable<object> ExecuteAndPromptCore(Page context)
    {
        PopupModel popupSettings = null;
        try
        {
            popupSettings = new PopupModel();
            ...
            yield return popupSettings;
        }
        finally
        {
            ...
        }
        yield break; 
    }
    ...
}
```

The IronPython script used in Spotfire to launch the new CustomTool (page is a Script Parameter of Type Page):

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference(".......")
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application
from CustomToolsWeb import CustomToolTwoWeb

found, tool = Application.Toolbox.TryGetTool[CustomToolTwoWeb]()
if found:
    tool.Execute(page)
```

Any Idea as why the new CustomTool does NOT show the Popup and the original CustomTool does.
How can this be fixed?

**PS:** Already tried `tool.ExecuteAndPrompt(page)` in the IronPython script but it does NOT execute my code (checked with debugger) and it also does NOT throw an error.

**UPDATE 2015-08-14:** From someone from TIBCO I got the following short answer:

> With the Web Player, the IronPython is executing on the server which
>   may be the issue. Because of this, the IronPython code probably cannot
>   open a pop-up window that displays to the user.

This seems a plausible technical explanation to me.

Is there any other way, out-of-the-box, the button can trigger my tool without the use of IronPython? Possibly through Javascript?

Or should I try building my own Ajax request to /SpotfireWeb/AjaxService.asmx ? Is this possible anyway?

Comment: Does tool.Execute(page) without the if statement not work as well? Also, have you tried running other methods available to the Tool class and printing them in the console such as GetType, IsEnabled, etc. just to see if they're returning anything?

Comment: @clesiemo3 That's just it,with the Visual Studio Debugger I attached to the IIS worker process and found out that Execute(page) get's to my C# code. However where in the original tool the yield return line would launch the prompt dialog, that line in the new tool does nothing. Not shown in the IronPython script above is that I also set 2 properties on the tool and when debugging the C# code I see that these properties do have the correct values.